# can we develop native ios apps with responsive?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, responsive-design, phonegap-build

I want informatin about how to make native IOS app which should be responsive design? 
If it is possible then how to make it. If it is not possible then how to make it possible with other way.

I have information about:

1. **[PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com/)** but i want to use native
2. **[swift framework](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/index.html)**.

*In between 1) and 2) which one should best and perfcet way to make resposive design?*

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AppKit/Reference/NSLayoutConstraint_Class/

Comment: Swift framework has a  development feature Autolayout that takes care of "responsiveness" in iOS native development. If you want to take the native route, you'll have use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To create responsive layout, you need to use `autolayout / constraint`.

Reference: http://blog.revivalx.com/2014/10/22/swift-autolayout-tutorial/

If you want to use native, you can integrate `native functionality` with `hybrid application` with develop a `custom cordova plugin`.

Reference: http://blog.revivalx.com/2014/03/11/ios-adding-native-functionality-to-hybrid-application-with-apache-cordova-plugin/

So far `phonegap` not support `swift` yet. It's support only for `objective-c (iOS)`. If you want you need to create a `bridging header` to communicate between swift and objective-c.

Reference: http://blog.revivalx.com/2014/12/30/bridging-between-swift-and-objective-c-in-the-same-project/

Let me know for more clarification.

Answer (score 1):

To achieve the "equivalent" of web responsive design in a native way, you have to use [Auto Layout concepts](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Introduction/Introduction.html) provided by the iOS SDK.

Other way, if you want to keep a web language, you'll soon be able to develop native applications in JavaScript with solutions like [React Native](https://code.facebook.com/videos/786462671439502/react-js-conf-2015-keynote-introducing-react-native-/) (still a private beta for now...)